# custom goals in google analytics with exceptions

Tags: google-analytics, goals

Im trying to setup a goal in google analytics that will track the following :

- any visit to the `/contact` page would be classed as a goal
- any visit to the `/contact` page, but if a user clicks a particular outgoing link from the contact, would not be considered a goal part of the same goal

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: Sorry, not following. What do you mean when you want to exclude clicks to an outside source. Do you mean outbound links? Also, I don't think you can use other conditions in a URL goal.

Comment: @nyuen ive updated the question should hopefully be clearer. what im trying to do really is track a user flow. so if a user goes to /contact and does 1 thing it counts as a goal, but goes to /contact and dose somthing else it wouldnt be counted as a goal

Comment: Ah, ok, the first part is doable (any visit to `/contact`), but the second part not so doable because as I mentioned, you can't include sequences or other things into a destination goal. You could try Custom Funnels though, where you can define a sequence of events and URLs.